# Traefik: the server could not find the requested resource

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, k3s, cert-manager

I have created a k3s cluster on some raspberry pis and am currently struggling to use the traefik service mesh to resolve to my domain.

I have previously got it working but upon recreating my cluster I cannot get pass the following problem:

The error message I am encountering in the traefik pod is the following:

```
Failed to watch *v1alpha1.IngressRouteUDP: failed to list *v1alpha1.IngressRouteUDP: the server could not find the requested resource
```

This error message is repeated many times with different resource types.

I am also getting the following error when trying to get a tls certificate from lets encrypt:

```
Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: wrong status code '404', expected '200
```

I have created a `clusterissuer` for a staging certificate with the following YAML:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: myemail@example.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: traefik
```

This appears to be working and returns the status `READY=true`

I have then requested a staging certificate with the YAML below:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: example-com
  namespace: cert-manager
  annotations:
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
  secretName: example-com-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-staging
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: example.com
  dnsNames:
  - example.com
```

This is where I encounter the `404` error which is outputted by the challenge.

I also have the following arguments in my traefik deployment:

```
      - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=myemail@example.com
        - --global.checknewversion
        - --global.sendanonymoususage
        - --entryPoints.traefik.address=:9000/tcp
        - --entryPoints.web.address=:8000/tcp
        - --entryPoints.websecure.address=:8443/tcp
        - --api.dashboard=true
        - --ping=true
        - --providers.kubernetescrd
        - --providers.kubernetesingress
        - --providers.kubernetesingress.ingressendpoint.publishedservice=kube-system/traefik
        - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls=true
        - --certificatesresolvers.default.acme.tlschallenge
        - --certificatesresolvers.default.acme.storage=acme.json
```

I am stumped. Have spent over a week trying to fix this and am sure it is something simple I am missing but I cannot work it out.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Sample of logs from traefik pod:

```
1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1alpha1.TraefikService: traefikservices.traefik.containo.us is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "traefikservices" in API group "traefik.containo.us" at the cluster scope
E1019 11:15:04.610288       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: endpoints is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "endpoints" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E1019 11:15:04.610542       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E1019 11:15:04.610902       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: ingresses.extensions is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "ingresses" in API group "extensions" at the cluster scope
E1019 11:15:04.610959       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1.Secret: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" at the cluster scope
E1019 11:15:04.658001       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1alpha1.IngressRouteTCP: ingressroutetcps.traefik.containo.us is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "ingressroutetcps" in API group "traefik.containo.us" at the cluster scope
E1019 11:15:04.861684       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1alpha1.IngressRoute: ingressroutes.traefik.containo.us is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "ingressroutes" in API group "traefik.containo.us" at the cluster scope
E1019 11:15:05.060807       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1alpha1.IngressRouteUDP: ingressrouteudps.traefik.containo.us is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "ingressrouteudps" in API group "traefik.containo.us" at the cluster scope
E1019 11:15:05.278868       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1alpha1.Middleware: middlewares.traefik.containo.us is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:traefik-ingress-controller" cannot list resource "middlewares" in API group "traefik.containo.us" at the cluster scope
```

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? Could you, please, provide your logs?

Comment: I am installing k3s v1.22.2 on a raspberry pi bare-metal cluster.
I have just updated the post to include some logs from traefik

Comment: I have resolved this issue by replacing traefik with nginx ingress. I have no idea what was causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify everything here. The solution that helped you was replacing traefik with nginx-ingress.

Let me explain possible reason why the first one didn't work.
I have found possible answer for your problem with traefik. [Here it is](https://community.traefik.io/t/migrating-from-swarm-to-k8s-mysql-problem/10919#:%7E:text=That%20means%20that%20Kubernetes%20run%20Traefik%20using%20a%20service%20account%2C%20but%20the%20SA%20has%20no%20access%20to%20the%20objects.%20That%27s%20why%20you%20need%20to%20create%20clusterRole%20and%20bind%20the%20created%20role%20using%20ClusterRoleBinding.).

Your logs say that Kubernetes runs Traefik using a Service Account, but the Service Account is lack of necessary access to the objects.

The problem was that you probably were lack of the ClusterRole and ClusteRoleBinding (that can allow the service account traefik-ingress-controller to see Kubernets resources including Traefik's CRDs).

See also [this documentation](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v1.7/user-guide/kubernetes//), where you can find examples.